# Handling scroll for a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview that has a swipe action

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Below is screenshot of a portion of an item in the primary recyclerview. The light green tiles are a secondary horizontal recycler view inside the primary recycler view. The primary recycler view has a swipe action to delete (indicated partially as well). The problem is that whenever the user scrolls the secondary recycler view the swipe action is triggered.

Expected result is that the swipe action is triggered whenever the user swipes anywhere outside of the secondary horizontal recycler view and the scroll action is triggered whenever the user scrolls any of the horizontal recycler view item.

This is where I trigger the swipe action for the recycler view:

```
SwipeToDeleteCallback swipeToDeleteCallback = new SwipeToDeleteCallback(context) {
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                final int position = viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
                adapter.removePlan(position);
            }
        };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchhelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback);
    itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview);
```

And this is the swipe touch helper callback:

```
    Context mContext;
    private final Paint mClearPaint;
    private final ColorDrawable mBackground;
    private final int backgroundColor;
    private final Drawable deleteDrawable;
    private final int intrinsicHeight;

    SwipeToDeleteCallback(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBackground = new ColorDrawable();
        backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.fullWhite);
        mClearPaint = new Paint();
        mClearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        deleteDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.icon_delete);
        intrinsicHeight = 240;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeMovementFlags(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int itemHeight = itemView.getHeight();

        boolean isCancelled = dX == 0 && !isCurrentlyActive;

        if (isCancelled) {
            clearCanvas(c, itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            return;
        }

        mBackground.setColor(backgroundColor);
        mBackground.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        mBackground.draw(c);
        deleteDrawable.setTint(Color.RED);

        int deleteIconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
        int deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
        int deleteIconLeft = itemView.getRight() - deleteIconMargin / 3 ;

        int deleteIconRight = itemView.getRight();
        int deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight;

        deleteDrawable.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom);
        deleteDrawable.draw(c);

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);


    }

    private void clearCanvas(Canvas c, Float left, Float top, Float right, Float bottom) {
        c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mClearPaint);

    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return 0.7f;
    }
```

[image]